# rsync over ssh hangs in a file sync daemon

Tags: qt, ssh, rsync

I am writing a file syncing application where I collect event from the filesystem whenever the file is modified and than later I copy it over to remote share via rsync over ssh. In my setup I have a slot which is connected to a QTimer. Each 5 seconds I pick a file from a sqlite db for synchronization and start a QProcess::start with the following parameters

```
/usr/bin/rsync -a /aufs/another-test-folder/testfile286.txt --rsh="ssh -p 8023" user@myserver.de:/home/neox/another-test-folder/testfile286.txt --rsync-path="mkdir -p /home/neox/another-test-folder && rsync"
```

I have at most 2 rsync processes running in parallel. This results in a process tree:

```
MyApp
  \_rsync
  |   \_ssh
  |_rsync
      \_ssh
```

The problem is that sometimes the application hangs and the ps says that ssh processes have gone zombie. First I have tried to kill MyApp with SIGKILL but no luck. Than I moved on to kill rsync and ssh but still no luck. The whole tree hangs. And if I try to start the daemon from another console or even try to ssh to another box, I can't. My idea here is that somewhere ssh blocks some IO resources. Any idea how to solve this?

P.S. This happens randomly and not often